# VBA assigning cell references function

Tags: excel, vba

I need a function that would assign cell references (through an Array with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER) to a worksheet. The problem is: that it works well unless a referenced cell is empty which gives #VALUE ERROR to ALL the cells part of the array. This is the function that I use

```
Function GeneratePackingList(PackageTable As Range)
Dim bRow As Byte, bCol as Byte
Dim asResult()
ReDim asResult(1 To 25, 1 To 11)

With PackageTable
    For bRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For bCol = 1 To 11
            Select Case bCol
                'Rearranging the columns order
                Case 1 To 6:    Set asResult(bRow, bCol) = .Cells(bRow, bCol + 1)
                Case 7:         Set asResult(bRow, bCol) = .Cells(bRow, 1)
                Case 8 To 11:   Set asResult(bRow, bCol) = .Cells(bRow, bCol)
            End Select
        Next bCol
    Next bRow
End With
GeneratePackingList = asResult
End Function
```

So basically if one of those cells from PackageTable is empty, i get the #VALUE Error and all is lost. should i change variable declaration (variant, range or else ??) is there any other more efficient way to assign cell references through a function?

Answer (score 2):

Using `Set` in your case clauses is causing `arResult` to be an array of `Range`s.  This is not necassary and is causeing your problem.  Just Delete the `Set`s

```
            Select Case bCol
                'Rearranging the columns order
                Case 1 To 6:     asResult(bRow, bCol) = .Cells(bRow, bCol + 1)
                Case 7:          asResult(bRow, bCol) = .Cells(bRow, 1)
                Case 8 To 11:    asResult(bRow, bCol) = .Cells(bRow, bCol)
            End Select
```

Comment: IF I am not using `Set`, `asResult` is a Variant array, and I cannot display cells with length > 255. It gives me an error. I need it to be a reference to the original cell not a just a pasted value through Variant.

Comment: You can't return a string value longer than 255 to an array, with or without the `Set`.

Comment: An array of strings seems to be able to hold more than 255 chars